# In Vim, can you show a tooltip where the cursor is?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to display a tooltip (like a popdown menu, but just with text), where the cursor is, using VimScript?

Comment: You can get a drop-down to help with [autocomplete](http://www.techrecipes.net/application/vim/enable-auto-complete?), is this what you're looking for?

Comment: you do not see the cursor? the blinking block? which os do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean a tooltip where the ***mouse*** cursor is, then you can do this by turning the `ballooneval` option on and setting the `bexpr` option to point to a function that returns your required tooltip.  This is only available if you're using a vim compiled with `+balloon_eval` (see `:version`).  Have a look at my (rather basic) [tag balloons script](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/tag-balloons) for an example.

If you mean a tooltip where the normal vim cursor is, I don't think there's a very clean way to do this.  You could create a custom menu with the text that you want (using amenu) and map the command to `:nop<CR>` and use `:popup` to display it:

```
amenu ]MyMenuName.The\ Text\ You\ Want :nop<CR>
popup ]MyMenuName
```

However, this will only work in the Win32 and GTK GUIs.

I don't know of a way to use the insert mode popup menu (the one used for `Ctrl-P` and omnicompletion etc) to just display some text.  You could abuse the completion method to give your own text as the completion alternative and set `menuone` in `completeopt` to allow a single line to be shown, but it would probably overwrite the current text with the contents of the popup menu.  It would probably also break omnicompletion!